# how to create a WIN CE 6.0 LCDdriver?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

this is vinoth. i am going to develop a new lcd driver which is for the external lcd panel(240*400 resolution) for win ce6.0 . am new t0 win ce programming . i dont know how to make changes all in the bsp and registry.if any one finds the answer pls help me. it would be very help ful for me.

Regards
Vinoth.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very heavy task. Are you sure your OEM does not provide an easy way to adjust the BSP to your display?

You have a sample display driver in the BSPs that ship with Platfrom Builder.

Did your board come without any display support? Maybe you only need to change some registry settings to make your display work.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Shaihi - this is a very big task, especially if you've not done drivers before.  The first thing to check is to see if the BSP contains a display driver already and possibly all you need to do is adjust it for your resolution, color depth etc.  If not, you need to check with the silicon vendor for whatever display controller you're using (be it in the processor or a separate controller) and see if they have a Windows CE reference driver that you can use as a starting point.

If you're starting from nothing with no resource but a data sheet, you have a couple months of work ahead of you.